# What is the best practice for security updates?

Tags: security, mirrors

For all of my official ubuntu updates (main universe multiverse restricted) I use an [Israeli mirror](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu) of the ubuntu repositories, with one exception: for the security updates I use http://security.ubuntu.com. The Israeli ISOC mirror also provides the security updates.

What are the pros and cons of using a mirror instead of the official repository for security updates? 
Are there any real security concerns I should consider by moving my security updated to a mirror instead of the official server?

Answer (score 2):

What I can think of:

- You might receive updates later than when using the main repository (due to the lag in synchronization),
- You might receive no updates at all if there's a problem with a mirror that's not closely monitored, and
- You might install problematic updates that have already been removed from the main repository (again, the lag in synchronization being the problem).

Security-wise I wouldn't worry that much, since packages and lists are all GPG-signed.