# URL for Ubuntu 16.04 security updates

Tags: apt, security

Which URL is recommended for [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) security updates?

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security ...
```

or

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security ...
```

Comment: Why would you change from the default, other than to select a mirror?

Comment: I see your point. Maybe it's related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/41728/what-is-the-best-practice-for-security-updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st URL.

Both locations hold the same software though so in the end it won't matter. As soon as Xenial reaches end of life only "archive" will be useable but it wont get any security updates anyways.

Comment: No, when releases reach EOL, they are moved off of archive and over to old-releases, and do not get any further security updates. Since 16.04 (Xenial) was just released, and is LTS, it also won't be EOL until April 2021.